# Regex to find space before a month name or abbreviation

Tags: regex, powershell

In a Powershell script I'm trying to write a regex to find the space before a month name or abbreviation (e.g. Jan, January, Feb, February, etc.).  I'm using this to drive the -replace operator.  I've constructed this regex that mostly works, but it also finds the space before works like Jane, Marcus, etc. I would like is to only find the space before the exact words such as Jan, January, Mar, March, etc. Any ideas?

```
[ ](?=Jan|(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Probably you need to escape the space: `[\ ]`

Comment: You need to define what may follow a month e.g. `\s` or `\W` or `\b` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got most of it right. The missing part is end-of-the-word anchor `\b`, which prevents matching prefixes of longer words:

```
\s(?=(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/bPYGVc/1)

**Note:** This also replaces `[ ]` with `\s`, which also matches tabs and newlines.